# "Have you gone" vs. "have you ever gone"

Tags: differences, adverbs, present-perfect

When talking about past experience, what is the difference between these two sentences?

> - Have you gone to Hong Kong?
> - Have you ever gone to Hong Kong?

Comment: I don't see the connection with the proposed duplicate (no mention of "been" here).

Comment: This is an incorrectly marked duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

*Ever* is roughly equivalent to *in your life*. So, for example, *Have you ever seen a ghost?* means *Have you in your life seen a ghost?* Sentences with *ever* are typical conversation starters:

> Have you ever ridden a horse?
>
> Have you ever been locked out of your house.

The same expressions without *ever* are generally about a single experience and are set in a context:

> You look pale! Have you seen a ghost?
>
> Why are you hanging around in the garden? Have you been locked out of your
>   house?

So the question *Have you gone to Hong Kong?* makes sense in the specific context of phoning someone on a world trip and not knowing where they are. But it is unlikely to be asked as a general question about life experience. A much more usual way of formulating the question would be: *Have you ever been to Hong Kong?*

Comment: Would you mind replicating this answer, with the necessary adjustments in the following question?: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30605/what-is-the-difference-between-ive-been-to-china-and-ive-gone-to-china I very much like the introduction in this answer, and I believe this aspect is often ignored in answers.